# Database mail Attach FileStream File

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, filestream

If I have a file stored in a FileStream column in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database can I attach that using Database Mail? If so what is the best method for doing so? My group would like to use the DBs database mail, but my only hangup with using it is when we need to attach a file that lives in one of our FileStream columns.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

S

Comment: I know its a little late now, but I'm trying to do the same thing. Any chance you can post an example of your procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a CLR procedure to perform this action.  It allowed me to stream the FileStream objects out of our File table and attach them to emails.  I wanted to avoid writing a custom process, but in the end it has worked out nicely.  If anyone wants an example post a comment and I can try to respond.

Comment: I know this was posted a long time ago, but I need to do this exact same thing.  Any chance you could post an example of what you did?